# Porque cuando uso placement new, me da segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando implementar un systema basado en componentes, todo funciona, el problema son los memory leak...
Alguien que me pueda dar una mano?

```
void initMQ7(ISensor* s, void* buf) {
    buf = operator new(sizeof(MQ7));
    s = new(buf) MQ7();
}

int main() {
    ISensor* sensor = NULL;
    void* buf = NULL;

    initMQ7(sensor,buf);
    sensor->print();
    sensor->~ISensor();
    operator delete (buf);

    return 0;   
}
```

Tambien destacar que este codigo no es el orientado a componentes, pero refleja el problema que tengo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con el *placement new*; simplemente, estas realizando **cambios locales** a la función, no visibles desde el exterior.

Estás pasando los argumentos **por copia**; es decir, dentro de la función lo que recibes es una copia de los argumentos originales; cualquier modificación que hagas **se pierde** al salir de la función, con lo que los argumentos originales no se ven afectados lo mas mínimo.

Simplemente, pasa los argumentos **por referencia**:

```
void initMQ7( ISensor *&s, void *&buf ) {
  buf = operator new( sizeof( MQ7 ) );
  s = new( buf ) MQ7( );
}
```

Comment: Es verdad que distrido ajaja gracias